# Bootstrap blocks - getting positioning and padding right

Tags: views, blocks, theming

I am using the bootstrap theme. I am generating pages that contain blocks from views. Getting the layout right is driving me insane.

For example, on one page I have one block generated from a view that should contain two bootstrap columns, followed by another block generated by a different view containing a single bootstrap column. So a row of three columns.

Bootstrap adds a clearfix to blocks so that immediately causes me issues - I remove it from the LHS block with Javascript, an inelegant hack. But then the padding is wrong if I don't wrap both blocks in a bootstrap row div. So I've been applying other classes to the blocks themselves to try to get around this.

I am aware I can make templates for pages, but using something like bootstrap is supposed to make layout easier, not cause headaches. Currently I would probably be better off just abandoning using Bootstrap and coding the layouts by hand.

What I am doing all feels very inelegant and hacky. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: IMO, removing clearfix isn't that good, because if you use col-md-* or some other col classes for your rows, then the rows won't be inside it's parent (because of float left). You can understand when you inspect them. I can't understand your exact problem, but in most cases clearfix class has solved many problems for me that's why I told not to remove clearfix class.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that with the Bootstrap theme, all blocks are wrapped in a class which contains the clearfix, so you can't put multiple blocks in bootstrap cols  in the same row. Which seems to defeat the purpose of using it.

Comment: Where are you placing these blocks? Sounds like you are doing it in the main page area. You need to create wrapper divs for your blocks and an upper layer of rows and cols. If you wrap a piece of html that ends with a clearfix in a div then that clearfix will only apply to the inside of the div.

Comment: Yes, in the main content area. I understand what needs to be done from a Bootstrap point of view - if I was doing it directly in an HTML page it would be easy. I understand how Bootstrap works. What I am having problems with is situations such as the example I gave - where I have columns and row containing content generated by different views. There doesn't seem to be a satisfactory way to do it, which kind of defeats the purpose of using Bootstrap with Drupal.